# Handling multiple dialogs in Microsoft bot framework

Tags: botframework

I am creating a bot using Microsoft bot framework , the bot will be receiving orders for a restaurant , I want to know how can I handle multiple dialogs , like for example the customer makes the first order , then i want the bot to ask do you want something else? then the customer says yes/no , incase of yes to repeat the same dailog again with keeping the state of the first one , what I am seeing in the documentation now is only one conversation and one dialog.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To manage multiple dialogs you need to use the [Dialog Chains](http://docs.botframework.com/sdkreference/csharp/dialogs.html#Fluent). You can either manage the stack of dialogs explicitly ([using Call/Done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37522294/calling-forms-from-dialogs/37525465#37525465)) or implicitly using the Chain fluent methods. [Here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Samples/EchoBot/EchoChainDialog.cs) is sample of how to use it.

If the set of things that the user can select are already predefined I would then recommend using [FormFlow](http://docs.botframework.com/sdkreference/csharp/forms.html). The [Pizza](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/master/CSharp/Samples/PizzaBot) & [Sandwich](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/master/CSharp/Samples/AnnotatedSandwichBot) samples are good examples of how to handle orders with a predefined set of options.

Comment: do you have a full tutorial on chains? I am not able to get it from the framework help page

Comment: I don't. You might to look to the EchoBot sample (https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/master/CSharp/Samples/EchoBot) and the Facebook sample (https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/master/CSharp/Samples/SimpleFacebookAuthBot) to get a better idea of how to use Chains. 

The anonymous method might confuse you. Think about it as a real chain. The output of the first item of the chain will be he input of the second item of the chain.

Chain.PostToChain()
.ContinueWith<Message, string>(Callback1)
 .PostToUser()
 .ContinueWith<string, string>(Callback2)

Comment: Dialog Chains appears to be a C# solution.  What is the equivalent for Node.js?

Comment: The closer I think it's Waterfall http://docs.botframework.com/builder/node/dialogs/overview/#waterfall

Comment: Would you please be able to explain how the Call/Done functions operate and where passed in values are sent?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37522294/calling-forms-from-dialogs/37525465#37525465

Comment: Thanks for this great answer, some or most of the links provided are now returning 404.

Answer (score 1):

With version V4 of Microsoft Bot Framework, FormFlow needs to be replaced by [Waterfall Dialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-dialog?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#dialog-types). Here we can use stepContext.Values (dictionary) to maintain state across waterfall steps and present user with choice prompt for Yes or No response and then repeat the waterfall dialog in case of Yes response else end the dialog in last waterfall step.

Add below waterfall in constructor of your base [Component dialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-dialog?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#component-dialog) and repeat the waterfall as per user choice.

```
WaterfallStep[] myWaterfallDialog = new WaterfallStep[]
{ 
    this.waterfallStepToGetUserOrder,
    .......
    this.promptUserForChoiceStep,
    this.EndDialogStep
}
AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog("mydialog", myWaterfallDialog);
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answers are good but I noticed some of the links provided are no longer working. Here is how I managed to navigate among different dialogs

```
    public MakeChoiceDialog() : base (nameof(MakeChoiceDialog))
    {
        AddDialog(new ChoicePrompt(nameof(ChoicePrompt)));
        AddDialog(new LoginDialog());
        AddDialog(new SignUpDialog());

        AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(nameof(WaterfallDialog), new WaterfallStep[]
            {
                LoginStepAsync,
                LoginSignUpStepAsync,
                //Other Steps here
            }));

        InitialDialogId = nameof(WaterfallDialog);
    }
```

The method call will be

```
    private async Task<DialogTurnResult> LoginSignUpStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        string userChoice = ((FoundChoice)stepContext.Result).Value;
        var msg = string.Empty;
        switch (userChoice)//You can use if statement here
        {
            case "Login":
                return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(LoginDialog), null, cancellationToken);
            default:                  
              return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(SignUpDialog), null, cancellationToken);
        }
        return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync(null, cancellationToken);
    }
```

In the **Startup.cs** add the following

```
services.AddSingleton<LoginDialog>();
services.AddSingleton<SignUpDialog>();
```