# Calling Forms from Dialogs

Tags: c#, botframework

I have a simple form,

```
 [Serializable]
class CreateNewLeadForm
{
    public string FirstName;
    public string LastName;
    public static IForm<CreateNewLeadForm> BuildForm()
    {

        return new FormBuilder<CreateNewLeadForm>()
            .Message("Lets create a New Lead")
            .Field(nameof(FirstName))
            .Field(nameof(LastName))
            .Build();

    }
};
```

And a simple Dialog,

```
public class GreetDialog : IDialog<object>
{        
    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {

        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
    }
    public   async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<Message> argument)
    {
       context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
    }  
}
```

How do I call a Initiate a FormDialog from the main Dialog itself? In general how do we intiate new dialogs within a Dialog?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to initiate a FormDialog you can just do:

```
var myform = new FormDialog<CreateNewLeadForm>(new CreateNewLeadForm(), CreateNewLeadForm.BuildForm, FormOptions.PromptInStart, null);

context.Call<CreateNewLeadForm>(myform, FormCompleteCallback);
```

Take a look to the [PizzaBot](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Samples/PizzaBot/PizzaOrderDialog.cs#L60) for an example.

To initiate new dialogs within a Dialog you can do:

- context.Call passing the instance of the new dialog and the completion callback (as in the form)
- context.Forward where you can *forward* the message to the child dialog

  context.Forward(new MyChildDialog(), ResumeAfterChildDialog, message, CancellationToken.None);