# IDialogContext.Forward causes the dialog to quit after one message in MS bot framework

Tags: botframework

I am using MS bot framework and trying to redirect the conversation from one dialog to another. If I use context.Call, the newly called dialog waits for the user to input any message first, which is undesirable. So I want to immediately start the new dialog. I am using context.Forward, which calls an instance of a FormDialog, but the newly created dialog outputs the first message, and then the whole dialog stack ends, returning me to the main screen of my bot.

```
await context.Forward<TestDialogForm, object>(
                TestDialog.GetDialog(), ChildTestDialogCompleted,
                string.Empty, CancellationToken.None);
```

What am I doing wrong? context.Call() works fine with the same dialog.

Comment: So you want to switch to the form dialog and immediately prompt for the first field? How are you building your form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See:
[Calling Forms from Dialogs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37522294/calling-forms-from-dialogs)

This works for me:

```
await context.Forward(
                new TestDialogForm(), 
                ChildTestDialogCompleted, 
                message, 
                System.Threading.CancellationToken.None);
```