# Why does a called dialog not wait for MessageReceivedAsync when it is called from another

Tags: c#, botframework

Hello everyone I'm building a bot using the Microsoft Bot Framework and I made a dispatch dialog which calls another dialog when it receives results from LUIS, but when I called the next dialog using the `context.Forward()` method, and it goes though the `public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)`
but though I use `context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);`
method, my dialog never waits for the user's message continues execution by going back to the dialog which called it.

I read answers [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38943075/idialogcontext-forward-causes-the-dialog-to-quit-after-one-message-in-ms-bot-fra)
but it does not resolve my problem.

This is how I call the Dialog:

```
await context.Forward(scheduleDialog,ScheduleDialogTerminated,context.MakeMessage(), CancellationToken.None);
```

Here is the Dialog called:

```
public class ScheduleDialog : IDialog
    {
        IScheduler scheduler;
        string timeEntity;
        string appointmentEntity;
        string dateEntity;

        public ScheduleDialog(IScheduler scheduler, string date, string time, string appointment) : base()
        {
            dateEntity = date;
            timeEntity = time;
            appointmentEntity = appointment;

            this.scheduler = scheduler;
        }

        public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
        {
            string message = context.Activity.AsMessageActivity().Text;
            await context.PostAsync($"Scheduling... {message}");
            context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
        }

        public async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> argument)
        {
            await context.PostAsync("Waiting for message...");
        }
    }
```

the `MessageReceivedAsync` method never gets called wereas I specified that the context should wait for it in the StartAsync method

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Here is how I call the Dialog:

Comment: It seems your comment was cut. Edit the post with the details please.

Comment: I edited the post please look at it now

Comment: The problem I have is though the dialog gets called well, it never waits for user messages, and exits emidiately after it passes the starAsync method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);` at the end of your `MessageReceivedAsync` method.

Comment: Did that helped? If so, please mark the question as answered please.