# How to call another dialog using same activity?

Tags: c#, botframework

```
[LuisIntent("test-intent")]
        public async Task test(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> argument, LuisResult result)
        {
            await Conversation.SendAsync(context.MakeMessage(), () => SimpleFacebookAuthDialog.dialog);
        }
```

I tried this. But the problem occurs when i try to send simple string message

```
await context.PostAsync("msg");
```

from SimpleFacebookAuthDialog. It throws an exception

> The data is changed.

context.MakeMessage() and Activity are not the same.

Some help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `context.Call` or `context.Forward` which are the ways to launch child dialogs instead of

```
 await Conversation.SendAsync(context.MakeMessage(), () => SimpleFacebookAuthDialog.dialog);
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37522294/calling-forms-from-dialogs/37525465#37525465) and the [MultiDialogs](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-MultiDialogs) sample for more information.

If you want to pass the same activity, then probably `context.Forward` is the way to go.

Comment: Please accept and upvote if it was useful. I provided some piece of advice on the other thread in GitHub (https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2110#issuecomment-275075947). Try moving the logic to a new dialog. But first try to read about al the core concepts involved.