# Bot Framework: Read the outgoing message of the Conversation

Tags: c#, botframework

Is there a way to use the Conversation so that the IMessageActivity to be sent to the user is returned to the caller instead of sent back to the user uri?
What I want to accomplish is to handle myself the incoming and outgoing messages, and while I can create an activity to be supplied to the Conversation object I cannot read and use the IMessageActivity reply.

To be more specific I'm wondering if I can substitute

```
Conversation.SendAsync(IMessageActivity, Func<IDialog<object>>);
```

With something that will let me handle the reply.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm following you... the reply should be handled by the dialog passed to the SendAsync method...

Comment: Wouldn't that prevent me from using FormFlow, PromptDialog etc etc, since they internally PostAsync to the context?

Comment: Not at all... you can use Dialogs and inside those dialogs call to FormFlow or any type of Prompt. Let me know if you need examples.

Comment: @ezequiel-jadib An example would he helpful, how would you get the output of, for example `PromptDialog.Confirm(context, ResumeAfter<bool>, "prompt dialogue", "retry dialog", 3)`

Comment: sure, check the answer below

Comment: @MatteoSaporiti if the answer helped you, you might consider checking that as your favorite one

Answer (score 0):

The reply should be handled by the dialog passed to the `SendAsync` method.

In the dialog, you will usually have a method that receives the context and the message sent by the user. For example:

```
public async virtual Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
{
   var message = await result;
}
```

In the `StartAsync` method of the dialog you will have to set this method as the one that will be called once the user sends a message to the bot

```
public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
{
    context.Wait(this.MessageReceivedAsync);
}
```

Then, is up to you to decide what to do after receiving the message.

Do you want to use a `PromptDialog`, e.g. the Confirm one? You can, just instantiate the dialog, call it and get the result in the `ResumeAfter<bool>` method.

```
PromptDialog.Confirm(context, ResumeAfterPrompt, "prompt dialogue", "retry dialog", 3);

private async Task ResumeAfterPrompt(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<bool> result)
{
    try
    {
        // try get user response
        bool response = await result;

        await context.PostAsync($"You said: {result}");
    }
    catch (TooManyAttemptsException)
    {
        // handle error
    }

   // wait for another message from the user. Could be the same method or a new one following the same signature.
   context.Wait(this.MessageReceivedAsync);
}
```

Do you want to use a FormFlow? You also, just instantiate the `FormDialog` and get the result in the `ResumeAfter<T>` method you define.

It's always the same pattern when working with multi dialogs (Prompts and Forms are dialogs!): call the dialog, get the result in the ResumeAfter method and wait for a new user message.

All this concepts are well explained and also demonstrated in the [Multi-Dialogs sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-MultiDialogs). Go through the readme and the codebase and you will understand what I explained. That sample shows prompts, a FormFlow, custom dialogs, etc. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37522294/calling-forms-from-dialogs/37525465#37525465) there are a few more details.

Comment: I probably didn't explain exactly what I wanted to get.
I know it's easy to get the result from the user, what I want to intercept is the content that the Dialog send to the user so something like
`{
  "type": "message",
  "channelId": "emulator",
  "from": {
    "id": "56800324",
    "name": "Bot1"
  },
  "recipient": {
    "id": "2c1c7fa3",
    "name": "User1"
  },
  "text": "Reply from the bot",
  "replyToId": "ba2f5b31398f48348b0f99427bed2e57"
}`
Because I want to send my reply to the client and not let the Connector send its own.

Comment: OK, use IActivityLogger to intercept the message. It won't prevent the Conversation to send it though

Comment: Minor question, what's your client? Explain a bit more your scenario; you a bot and a custom client?