# FormDialog display some specific fields from Model class Bot framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I want to display a **DialogForm** in my **RootDialog**. I've tried to do it by doing like [calling forms from dialogs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37522294/calling-forms-from-dialogs). However, my problem here is I have a model class generated by Entity Framework which contains some fields about primary key (or Foreign key) that I don't want my client to enter input for it. So my question is how can I make a DialogForm that just ask my clients to enter the fields that I want to?
Here's my Model class:

```
[Serializable]
public partial class BOT_CUSTOMERINFO
{

    public int CUSTOMER_ID { get; set; }

    public Nullable<int> DOMAIN_ID { get; set; }
    public string NAME { get; set; }
    public string EMAIL { get; set; }
    public string PHONE { get; set; }

    public Nullable<int> RECORD_STATUS { get; set; }

    public static IForm<BOT_CUSTOMERINFO> BuildForm()
    {

        return new FormBuilder<BOT_CUSTOMERINFO>()
            .Message("Vui lòng cung cấp thông tin")
            .Field(nameof(NAME))
            .Field(nameof(EMAIL))
            .Field(nameof(PHONE))
            .Field(new FieldReflector<BOT_CUSTOMERINFO>(nameof(CUSTOMER_ID)).SetActive((state) => false))
            .Build();

    }

}
```

And hence what I've used to call FormDialog:

```
private BuildFormDelegate<Models.FormDialog_Models.CustomerInfoFormModel> MakeCustomerInfoForm;

    internal void CustomerInfoDialog(BuildFormDelegate<Models.BOT_CUSTOMERINFO> makeCustomerInfoForm)
    {

        this.MakeCustomerInfoForm = makeCustomerInfoForm;

    }
    public async Task ResumeAfterChooseQuestion(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<BOT_QUESTION> result)
    {
        var value = await result;
        if(value != null)
        {
            BotDBEntities DbContext = new BotDBEntities();
            if(DbContext.BOT_ANSWER.Any(answer => answer.QUESTION_ID == value.QUESTION_ID))
            {
                List<BOT_ANSWER> ListAnswer = DbContext.BOT_ANSWER.Where(answer => answer.QUESTION_ID == value.QUESTION_ID).ToList();
                await ShowListAnswer(context, ListAnswer);
                //PromptDialog.Choice(context, this.ResumeAfterChooseAnswer,ListAnswer, "Click để chọn:", "Không hợp lệ", 3, PromptStyle.Auto);
            }
            if(DbContext.BOT_QUESTION.Any(question => question.PREVQUESTION_ID == value.QUESTION_ID))
            {
                List<BOT_QUESTION> ListQuestion = DbContext.BOT_QUESTION.Where(question => question.PREVQUESTION_ID == value.QUESTION_ID).ToList();
                await this.ShowListQuestion(context, ListQuestion);
            }
            if(value.QUESTION_TYPE.Value == 1)
            {
                var customerInfoForm = new FormDialog<Models.BOT_CUSTOMERINFO>(new Models.BOT_CUSTOMERINFO(), MakeCustomerInfoForm, FormOptions.PromptInStart);

                context.Call(customerInfoForm, CustomerInfoFormCompleted);
                // var customerInfoForm = new FormDialog<Models.FormDialog_Models.CustomerInfoFormModel>(new Models.FormDialog_Models.CustomerInfoFormModel(),MakeCustomerInfoForm, FormOptions.PromptInStart);
                // context.Forward(customerInfoForm, CustomerInfoFormCompleted);
                // context.Call(customerInfoForm, CustomerInfoFormCompleted);
                //context.Call<Idia<BOT_CUSTOMERINFO>>(BOT_CUSTOMERINFO.BuildForm(), CustomerInfoFormCompleted);
            }

        }
        else
        {

            context.Wait(this.MessageReceiveAsync);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the declaration of your `FormBuilder<BOT_CUSTOMERINFO>` you can deactivate those fields, using the [Advanced.Field.SetActive](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/d2/d1b/class_microsoft_1_1_bot_1_1_builder_1_1_form_flow_1_1_advanced_1_1_field.html#a048ce0f4bd1841ad37f3ed5f6e2df933).

```
new FormBuilder<BOT_CUSTOMERINFO>
.Field(new FieldReflector<BOT_CUSTOMERINFO>(nameof(CUSTOMER_ID))
      .SetActive((state) => false);
```

Comment: So I have to create a BuildForm method in my Model class and set Deactive and finally it will be done automatically when I create it by call context.Call() method ?

Comment: In your model or in any other place; it doesn't matter. Yes it should work this way,

Comment: Actually, I've added this line of code to my BOT_CUSTOMERINFO class but it didn't work

Comment: Post the full code; otherwise it's hard to know what's wrong. I know this works as it's being used in many places

Comment: But... the FormFlow is being created with a different model... CustomerInfoFormModel. If you are using a different model, then you need to deactivate the fields in that model and not in the BOT_CUSTOMERINFO.

Comment: It still display the CUSTOMER_ID field in the emulator. I've just replaced the wrong code.

Comment: I've made it just like the PizzaBot Sample did

Comment: BOT_CUSTOMERINFO class: https://codepaste.net/hucurn
Create FormDialog method: https://codepaste.net/d7ak2q

Comment: Code looks good to me... so the Form is asking you to fill the customer id?

Comment: yes, notice that i'm creating FormDialog in a Dialog Class

Comment: shouldn't be an issue

Comment: It would be great if you can create a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable sample and uploaded somewhere so it can be downloaded and debugged.

Comment: can we have a private chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137673/discussion-between-justin-van-and-ezequiel-jadib).

Comment: I've noticed that when I set the breakpoint to the BuildForm method, it absolutely didn't invoke

Comment: It's because you are using MakeCustomerInfo instead of the BuildForm method

Comment: well, so how can we change it ?

Comment: var customerInfoForm = new FormDialog<Models.BOT_CUSTOMERINFO>(new Models.BOT_CUSTOMERINFO(), BOT_CUSTOMERINFO.BuildForm, FormOptions.PromptInStart);

Comment: Finally, that solves my problem. Thanks for supporting me!