# How to call carousel in my luis dialog

Tags: c#, bots, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I want to call a dialog class (where I have added carousel).

Here is my code

```
[LuisIntent("Greeting")]
public async Task Greeting(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
{
    context.Call(new GuesserBot, this.ResumeAfterOptionDialog);
}
```

Carousel is in a new page:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace project.Dialogs
{
public class GuesserBot
{
    public class GuesserDialog : IDialog<object>
    {
        string strBaseURL;
        protected int intNumberToGuess;
        protected int intAttempts;

        #region public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
        public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
        {
            // Generate a random number
            Random random = new Random();
            this.intNumberToGuess = random.Next(1, 6);

            // Set Attempts
            this.intAttempts = 1;

            // Start the Game
            context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
        }
        #endregion

        public virtual async Task MessageReceivedAsync(
            IDialogContext context,
            IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> argument)
        {
            // Set BaseURL
            context.UserData.TryGetValue<string>(
                "CurrentBaseURL", out strBaseURL);

            int intGuessedNumber;

            // Get the text passed
            var message = await argument;

            // See if a number was passed
            if (!int.TryParse(message.Text, out intGuessedNumber))
            {
                // A number was not passed  

                // Create a reply Activity
                Activity replyToConversation = (Activity)context.MakeMessage();
                replyToConversation.Recipient = replyToConversation.Recipient;
                replyToConversation.Type = "message";

                string strNumberGuesserCard =
                    String.Format(@"{0}/{1}",
                    strBaseURL,
                    "Images/NumberGuesserCard.png");

                List<CardImage> cardImages = new List<CardImage>();
                cardImages.Add(new CardImage(url: strNumberGuesserCard));

                // Create the Buttons
                // Call the CreateButtons utility method
                List<CardAction> cardButtons = CreateButtons();

                // Create the Hero Card
                // Set the image and the buttons
                HeroCard plCard = new HeroCard()
                {
                    Images = cardImages,
                    Buttons = cardButtons,
                };

                // Create an Attachment by calling the
                // ToAttachment() method of the Hero Card                
                Attachment plAttachment = plCard.ToAttachment();
                // Attach the Attachment to the reply
                replyToConversation.Attachments.Add(plAttachment);
                // set the AttachmentLayout as 'list'
                replyToConversation.AttachmentLayout = "list";

                // Send the reply
                await context.PostAsync(replyToConversation);
                context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
            }

            // This code will run when the user has entered a number
            if (int.TryParse(message.Text, out intGuessedNumber))
            {
                // A number was passed
                // See if it was the correct number
                if (intGuessedNumber != this.intNumberToGuess)
                {
                    // The number was not correct
                    this.intAttempts++;

                    // Create a response
                    // This time call the ** ShowButtons ** method
                    Activity replyToConversation =
                        ShowButtons(context, "Not correct. Guess again.");

                    await context.PostAsync(replyToConversation);
                    context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Game completed
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    sb.Append("Congratulations! ");
                    sb.Append("The number to guess was {0}. ");
                    sb.Append("You needed {1} attempts. ");
                    sb.Append("Would you like to play again?");

                    string CongratulationsStringPrompt =
                        string.Format(sb.ToString(),
                        this.intNumberToGuess,
                        this.intAttempts);

                    // Put PromptDialog here
                    PromptDialog.Confirm(
                        context,
                        PlayAgainAsync,
                        CongratulationsStringPrompt,
                        "Didn't get that!");
                }
            }
        }

        private async Task PlayAgainAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<bool> result)
        {
            // Generate new random number
            Random random = new Random();
            this.intNumberToGuess = random.Next(1, 6);

            // Reset attempts
            this.intAttempts = 1;

            // Get the response from the user
            var confirm = await result;

            if (confirm) // They said yes
            {
                // Start a new Game
                // Create a response
                // This time call the ** ShowButtons ** method
                Activity replyToConversation =
                    ShowButtons(context, "Hi Welcome! - Guess a number between 1 and 5");
                await context.PostAsync(replyToConversation);
                context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
            }
            else // They said no
            {
                await context.PostAsync("Goodbye!");
                context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
            }
        }

        // Utility

        #region private static List<CardAction> CreateButtons()
        private static List<CardAction> CreateButtons()
        {
            // Create 5 CardAction buttons 
            // and return to the calling method 
            List<CardAction> cardButtons = new List<CardAction>();
            for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
            {
                string CurrentNumber = Convert.ToString(i);
                CardAction CardButton = new CardAction()
                {
                    Type = "imBack",
                    Title = CurrentNumber,
                    Value = CurrentNumber
                };

                cardButtons.Add(CardButton);
            }

            return cardButtons;
        }
        #endregion

        #region private static Activity ShowButtons(IDialogContext context, string strText)
        private static Activity ShowButtons(IDialogContext context, string strText)
        {
            // Create a reply Activity
            Activity replyToConversation = (Activity)context.MakeMessage();
            replyToConversation.Text = strText;
            replyToConversation.Recipient = replyToConversation.Recipient;
            replyToConversation.Type = "message";

            // Call the CreateButtons utility method 
            // that will create 5 buttons to put on the Here Card
            List<CardAction> cardButtons = CreateButtons();

            // Create a Hero Card and add the buttons 
            HeroCard plCard = new HeroCard()
            {
                Buttons = cardButtons
            };

            // Create an Attachment
            // set the AttachmentLayout as 'list'
            Attachment plAttachment = plCard.ToAttachment();
            replyToConversation.Attachments.Add(plAttachment);
            replyToConversation.AttachmentLayout = "list";

            // Return the reply to the calling method
            return replyToConversation;
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
}
```

I got this error:

> Error CS0411: The type arguments for method 'IDialogStack.Call(IDialog, ResumeAfter)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

ResumeAfterOption :

```
 private async Task ResumeAfterOptionDialog(IDialogContext context,          IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        await context.PostAsync("Do you want something else!");
    }
```

Can you help me how to show a carousel when one intent is called?

Can I do it add carousel code in the same class where I have my luis dialog intent?

Comment: Please show the code for the ResumeAfterOptionDialog. Also you are missing a () after the new GuesserBot...

Comment: @EzequielJadib i added ResumeAfterOption .. In my code is ok GuesserBot() ..but still i got the error

Comment: Your code has 2 nested classes. GuesserBot and GuesserDialog.. you should call GuesserDialog...

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are trying to *call* something that is not a dialog and so the compiler cannot infer the type. By looking at your code, it seems you are trying to call `GuesserBot` (which is not a dialog), however you should be calling to `GuesserDialog`.

```
[LuisIntent("Greeting")]
public async Task Greeting(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
{
    context.Call(new GuesserDialog(), this.ResumeAfterOptionDialog);
}
```

BTW, I noticed that your `GuesserDialog` is not serializable, so make sure to add the `[Serializable]` attribute to it; otherwise it will fail later.

Regarding your second question, yes, you can add the carousel code in the your LuisDialog based class.

Comment: can you please sen me any code some how can i do it ?@ezequiel

Comment: i add [Serializable] but still not fixed

Comment: Code about what? And what's not fixed? Have you changed the context.Call line? You are calling GuesserBot and that's wrong.

Comment: context.Call(new GuesserBot(), this.ResumeAfterOptionDialog);

Comment: [Serializable]
    public class GuesserBot
    {
        public class GuesserDialog : IDialog<object>
        {

Comment: That's wrong.. pleas read my answer carefully.. you need to do context.Call(new GuesserDialog(), this.ResumeAfterOptionDialog); and the [Serializable] must be on top of the GuesserDialog.. I'm not sure why you have two nested classes either.

Comment: Thank you ...it's ok now

Comment: Great, please upvote (if you can) and mark the question as answered

Comment: i tried using the  context.Call(new GuesserDialog(), this.ResumeAfterOptionDialog); on the first fire of the message, it will not do anything, i need to retype the message again for my carousel to load. any ideas?

Comment: use context.Forward instead of context.Call check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37522294/calling-forms-from-dialogs/37525465#37525465