# multiple LUIS dialog , switch based on the language text

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

I have two LUIS dialogs created using c# bot framework. I am unable to switch to another LUIS dialog once the language changes

In the closing intent I am using postAsync method to post the msg

After that if I don't use context.wait(this.messagetecieived) , dialog switches but it throws error.

If I use context.wait it will goes to infinite loop and it never ends the dialog

I tried using context.done. but no use.

Please help me

Comment: You should add the BotFramework tag to have this show up for the Bot Framework support team.

Comment: THanks Jim for the suggestion

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling Forms from Dialogs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37522294/calling-forms-from-dialogs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To move to different dialogs you have to use `context.forward` or `context.call`. Please refer the sample [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-MultiDialogs) which shows how to switch between dialogs.

Comment: here the issue is, i have two languages services. based on the language i am forwarding it to specific dialog. For ex. If the service recognizes language as English, it will forward it EnglishDialog. After if the input is French langauge, it recognizes language, but it does not load FrenchDialog, instead it loads the same EnglishDialog

Comment: If you move or forwarded your context to one child dialog give context.Done to exit from that particular child dialog.