# Proactive messaging with prompt buttons - Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: c#, botframework

I've been playing around with proactive messaging, but I'm not sure how to achieve something like this. I've got a service that messages users products on a daily basis. Using a resumption cookie I call an end point, build a response by setting the `.Text` property and create the carousel of products by populating the `.Attachments` property. I want to add buttons to this message to allow a user to stop the alerts, but the only event a CardAction button allows is opening an URL in a web browser. Is there a way of creating a button which can trigger a method, or call a new dialog?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use the `ImBack` or `PostBack` [ActionTypes](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Shared/ActionTypes.cs) on the `CardAction`. Clicking on a button when using any of those, will send a message to the conversation with the `Value` of the action that will end up *arriving* to the method you are "waiting" (by doing `context.Wait(...)`);

Then, in that method you can do whatever you want: [call a new dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37522294/calling-forms-from-dialogs/37525465#37525465) or any other logic you want to trigger.

In the [ContosoFlowers](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/CSharp/demo-ContosoFlowers/ContosoFlowers/) sample you can see [how a card with buttons is used in that way](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/CSharp/demo-ContosoFlowers/ContosoFlowers/Dialogs/RootDialog.cs#L63-L78).