# Is Chain.From Required for FormFlow IDialog<T>

Tags: c#, botframework

Examples, like SandwichBot, use `Chain.From` to return the `IDialog<T>` for `SendAsync`, like this:

```
    internal static IDialog<SandwichOrder> MakeRootDialog()
    {
        return Chain.From(() => FormDialog.FromForm(SandwichOrder.BuildForm));
    }
```

I can see that `Chain.From` pushes and pops the `IFormDialog<T>`, returned from `FormDialog.FromForm`, but am not sure what the benefit of that is. However, the chatbot still works without `Chain.From`, as shown below:

```
    internal static IDialog<SandwichOrder> MakeRootDialog()
    {
        return FormDialog.FromForm(SandwichOrder.BuildForm);
    }
```

Since the examples use `Chain.From`, it makes me think that it might be somehow required or recommended. What is the rationale for `Chain.From`, where would it be required, and what are the drawbacks to the simpler syntax without it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [SimpleSandwichBot](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/master/CSharp/Samples/SimpleSandwichBot) I believe that it doesn't make sense to have the `Chain.From`, however I suspect that was done to allow a seamless transition to the [AnnotatedSandwichBot](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Samples/AnnotatedSandwichBot/Controllers/MessagesController.cs#L19) where the `Chain` is being used a bit more.

Personally I don't use `Chain` a lot unless I need to put together something really simple and I don't want to create a dialog as it could easily become complex to read/follow.

With `Chain` you can manage the stack of dialogs implicitly. However, explicit management of the stack of dialogs ([using Call/Done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37522294/calling-forms-from-dialogs/37525465#37525465)) seems to be better to composing larger conversations. Creating new dialogs it's more verbose (especially in `C#`) but I believe it allows to organize better the solution and the code.

I don't think there is a place where `Chain` is required as it's not providing anything unique, just a fluent interface that is usable in `LINQ` query syntax.

The drawbacks I see are mainly around complexity of the resulting code if you are trying to create something big. If I don't misremember, there is also a chance of getting a serialization issue depending how you are using it.

From the [docs](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/dialogs.html#Serialization):

> The Chain methods provide a fluent interface to dialogs that is usable in LINQ query syntax. The compiled form of LINQ query syntax often leverages anonymous methods. If these anonymous methods do not reference the environment of local variables, then these anonymous methods have no state and are trivially serializable. However, if the anonymous method captures any local variable in the environment, the resulting closure object (generated by the compiler) is not marked as serializable. The Bot Builder will detect this situation and throw a ClosureCaptureException to help diagnose the issue.