# How to switch between two luis.ai dialog with different languages

Tags: c#, facebook, azure, botframework, azure-language-understanding

i have created a bot in bot framework using also luis.ai.

In my luis account i have created two app with different language culture. One app in english and other in french. Both have their intents.

In my code i call one time english dialog, and other time french luis dialog .

My problem is that when i start conversation in english facebook channel ( messenger ) i get the right answer. Inside this bot and channel when i type in french , my bot don't call french dialog .

When i start conversation  in french version of facebook ...the bot can't recognize the right dialog ...but catch an error : "Ooops! There are some problems with our system

I try to type english utterance and then i get : Ooops! Too many attemps :(. But don't worry, I'm handling that exception and you can try again!

My idea is that : when i'm inside facebook in english language and click : Get Started ...my conversation to start in english dialog ( AlltheBot.cs). If i type french word like : salut, demarrer the bot can forward to french dialog ( FrenchLuis.cs) . And the other way around, when i'm in facebook in french version my conversation when i click on Demarrer to start in french , and then if i type hello to forward in english dialog.

My code is here :

MessageController.cs

```
namespace MultiDialogsBot
 {
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;
using FirstBotApplication.Dialogs;
using System.Linq;
using System;

[BotAuthentication]
public class MessagesController : ApiController
{
    /// <summary>
    /// POST: api/Messages
    /// Receive a message from a user and reply to it
    /// </summary>
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
    {
        if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
        {
            await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new RootDialog());
        }
        else
        {
            this.HandleSystemMessage(activity);
        }

        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        return response;
      }

     private Activity HandleSystemMessage(Activity message)
     {
        if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.DeleteUserData)
        {
            // Implement user deletion here
            // If we handle user deletion, return a real message
        }
        else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate)
        {
            // Handle conversation state changes, like members being added 
       and removed
            // Use Activity.MembersAdded and Activity.MembersRemoved and 
         Activity.Action for info

            IConversationUpdateActivity update = message;
            var client = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(message.ServiceUrl), 
           new MicrosoftAppCredentials());
            if (update.MembersAdded != null && update.MembersAdded.Any())
            {
                foreach (var newMember in update.MembersAdded)
                {
                    if (newMember.Id != message.Recipient.Id && newMember.Id 
             != message.Conversation.Id)
                    {
                        var reply = message.CreateReply();
                        reply.Text = $"Welcome" + " " + 
      message.Recipient.Name + " ! You are a new member! If you want to see 
                   help menu , type : help";
                        client.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
                    }
                }
            }
            // Not available in all channels
        }
        else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ContactRelationUpdate)
        {
            // Handle add/remove from contact lists
            // Activity.From + Activity.Action represent what happened
        }
        else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.Typing)
        {
            // Handle knowing tha the user is typing
        }
        else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.Ping)
        {
        }

        return null;
    }


}
```

}

RootDialog.cs

```
namespace FirstBotApplication.Dialogs
 {
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;

[Serializable]
public class RootDialog : IDialog<object>
{


    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        context.Wait(this.MessageReceivedAsync);
    }

    public virtual async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, 
      IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
    {
        var message = await result;

        if (message.Text.ToLower().Contains("Get Started") || 
       message.Text.ToLower().Contains("hello") || 
         message.Text.ToLower().Contains("hi"))
        {
            context.Call(new AllTheBot (), this.ResumeAfterOptionDialog);

        }

        else if (message.Text.ToLower().Contains("Démarrer") || 
     message.Text.ToLower().Contains("salut") || 
        message.Text.ToLower().Contains("french"))
        {
            context.Call(new FrenchLuis(), this.ResumeAfterOptionDialog);

        }
        else
        {
            await context.PostAsync($"Ooops! There are some problems with our system");
        }

    }

    private async Task ResumeAfterOptionDialog(IDialogContext context, 
     IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        await context.PostAsync($"Ooops! Too many attemps :(. But don't 
   worry, I'm handling that exception and you can try again!");
    }

      }
    }
```

FrenchLuis.cs

```
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Luis;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Luis.Models;
 using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;
 using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;


   namespace FirstBotApplication
    {
    //  [LuisModel("Please Enter Your LUIS Model ID", "Please Enter Your 
     LUIS 
     Subscription Key")]

  [Serializable]

 [LuisModel("aaaaaaa", "xxxxxxxxx")]



public class FrenchLuis : LuisDialog<object>
{
    internal static string results;

    // internal static string results;
    [LuisIntent("None")]
    [LuisIntent("")]
    public async Task None(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        string message = $"Désolé je n'ai pas compris '{result.Query}'. 
     Veuillez reformuler votre question";

        await context.PostAsync(message);

        context.Wait(this.MessageReceived);
        context.Done(true);

    }



    //french luis.ai
    [LuisIntent("demarrerintent")]
    public async Task demarrerintent(IDialogContext context, 
   IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> activity, LuisResult result)
    {

        await context.PostAsync("Bienvenue :) ");

         context.Done(true);


    }

    [LuisIntent("denous")]
    public async Task denous(IDialogContext context, 
   IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> activity, LuisResult result)
    {

        await context.PostAsync(" Nous sommes .....");

        context.Done(true);
    }

    [LuisIntent("quisommes")]
    public async Task quisommes(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> activity, LuisResult result)
    {

        await context.PostAsync("Je suis un robot");
        context.Done(true);
        // context.Wait(MessageReceived);

    }
  }}
```

AllTheBot.cs

```
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Luis;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Luis.Models;
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;
   using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
  using System.Threading.Tasks;
 using System.Web;


  namespace FirstBotApplication
     {

    [LuisModel("bbbbbb", "xxxxxxx")]

   [Serializable]


  public class AllTheBot : LuisDialog<object>
   {
    internal static string results;

    // internal static string results;
    [LuisIntent("None")]
    [LuisIntent("")]
    public async Task None(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        string message = $"Sorry, I did not understand '{result.Query}'. 
       Please reformulate your question";

        await context.PostAsync(message);
        context.Done(true);

        //  context.Wait(this.MessageReceived);

    }


    [LuisIntent("grettings")]
    [LuisIntent("intentfr")]
    public async Task Greeting(IDialogContext context, 
    IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> activity, LuisResult result)
    {


            await context.PostAsync("Welcome ");

        context.Done(true);

    }



    [LuisIntent("test")]
    public async Task test(IDialogContext context, 
    IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> activity, LuisResult result)
    {
        await context.PostAsync("Do you want to test our bot ? We suggest to 
    type : hi or who are you, help etc..");
        context.Wait(MessageReceived);
    }
    }}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a look to your project and got a few problems. You should go step by step to eliminate the problems as you are mixing many things (Dialog management, LUIS calls etc.)

**RootDialog.cs**

*1st point:*

```
message.Text.ToLower().Contains("Démarrer")
```

and

```
message.Text.ToLower().Contains("Get Started")
```

Those two tests can't be valid, as you are comparing something in lowercase and a word with an uppercase.

Moreover, there are better clever ways to get the events of Facebook Messenger 'Get Started' button click, but that's not the point here.

*2nd point:*

```
private async Task ResumeAfterOptionDialog(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
{
    await context.PostAsync($"Ooops! Too many attemps :(. But don't worry, I'm handling that exception and you can try again!");
}
```

Your text here is quite strange for a dialog resume!

**AllTheBot.cs and FrenchLuis.cs**

When you call your 2 LuisDialog, you are never passing the value of the message to those dialogs, is this normal?

You should use `context.Forward` instead of `context.Call`: in that way your message will automatically be forwarded to the child dialog.

**Global behaviour**

I don't think you are going to the right way for managing languages. Why don't you use a valid Language Detection system to check which language is the content you received from the user?

The Text Analytics API from Microsoft Cognitive Services is here for this: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/cognitive-services/text-analytics/

**Dialog management in your case**

I made a sample of the implementation of 2 dialogs management (without LUIS here) to show you what's working:

```
[Serializable]
public class Dialog44592511 : IDialog<object>
{
    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
    }

    public virtual async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
    {
        var message = await result;

        if (message.Text.ToLower().Contains("Get Started") ||
            message.Text.ToLower().Contains("hello") ||
            message.Text.ToLower().Contains("hi"))
        {
            await context.Forward(new Dialog44592511_EN(), this.ResumeAfterOptionDialog, message);
        }
        else if (message.Text.ToLower().Contains("Démarrer") || message.Text.ToLower().Contains("salut") || message.Text.ToLower().Contains("french"))
        {
            await context.Forward(new Dialog44592511_FR(), this.ResumeAfterOptionDialog, message);
        }
        else
        {
            await context.PostAsync($"Ooops! There are some problems with our system");
        }
    }

    private async Task ResumeAfterOptionDialog(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        await context.PostAsync($"Resume!");
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class Dialog44592511_FR : IDialog<object>
{
    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
    }

    private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        var activity = await result as Activity;
        await context.PostAsync($"Vous êtes dans le dialogue FR");
        context.Done<object>(null);
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class Dialog44592511_EN : IDialog<object>
{
    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
    }

    private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        var activity = await result as Activity;
        await context.PostAsync($"You are in the EN dialog");
        context.Done<object>(null);
    }
}
```

[image: Test]

Don't hesitate to edit your question for more details

Comment: Thanks @ezequiel-jadib for the point I changed the way the dialogs are called

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing `context.Call`, you should use `context.Forward`, which will forward the message to the dialog.

With the `context.Call` you are just calling the dialog and leaving it ready to receive a new message.

You should review the different ways to initiate dialogs, explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37522294/calling-forms-from-dialogs).

Comment: @Nicolas thnx for your code ... i have still problem ( my bot turn only error : Ooops! There are some problems with our system)  when i try to start conversation( in french or english )  from a facebook ( in french language ) ...and in other in english version , if i am talking in english and start to type something in french , my bot can't understand and send me :($"Ooops! There are some problems with our system")

Comment: i continue to to have problem ... i made all changes but nothing :(