# Can I have multiple controllers in bot?? if yes then how can i handle the end points

Tags: dialog, bots, botframework, controllers, azure-language-understanding

I am working on bot framework and just start to do things in this can any one let me know can I build multiple controllers in this.?/

Comment: ôf course you could have multiple controllers in one project. You would need to have an Connector linked to that controller. Doing this with anything else then Directline seems not possible. But i dont see any value in using more then one controller. your conversationallogic does not go into the controller but in the root dialog of your bot.

Comment: okay Thank you for your reply can you please just tell me any resource where I can understand dialog chaining properly using luis because I am using LUIS intent ... it will be more usefull for me. I have read the bot documents  and they give just normal dialog chaining not with LUIS. Hope you will guide me in this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using C#:

you can call multiple dialogs and there are multiple ways to do it. Some dialog documentation can be found [In this blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-dialogs).  Also there is some great information and links in [This Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37169371/handling-multiple-dialogs-in-microsoft-bot-framework). Here are a couple of examples of how to use multiple dialogs.

using Chain when calling a form where `PizzaOrderDialog` is a form:

```
internal static IDialog<PizzaOrderDialog> MakeFormDialog()
{
            return Chain.From(() => FormDialog.FromForm(PizzaOrderDialog.BuildForm));
}
```

This is an example of forwarding a dialog:

```
await context.Forward(new SomeDialog(), ResumeAfterSomeDialog, context.Activity.AsMessageActivity(), CancellationToken.None);
```

In your case you may need to use [Scoreables](https://github.com/Microsoft/bf-blog/blob/gh-pages/_posts/2017/2017-07-06-Scorables.md)  also [Great Video Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hnU3lPHhv88).