# How call Dialog from FormFlow

Tags: c#, botframework, formflow

How to call dialog in the middle of Form?
I would like to call Location dialog https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Location to get address.
Thanks.

```
[Serializable]
public class IssueShares
{
    [Prompt("Please enter holder name:")]
    public string HolderName;
    [Prompt("Please enter holder address:")]
   **[Call(typeof(AddressDialog))]**
    public Address Address;

    [Prompt("Enter shares class:")]
    public string SharesClass { get; set; }
    [Prompt("How many shares your issue?")]
    [Describe("Number of shares")]
    public int NumberOfShares { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class AddressDialog : IDialog<Address>
{
    public Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        context.Wait(MessageReceived);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task MessageReceived(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        // some logic
        context.Done(address);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not currently a feature.

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting a solution based on an attribute declaration or is regular code acceptable?

Microsoft offers Dialog Chaining invoked as a sequence or a stack.

The accepted answer in the follow SO question answers your question I think.

[Calling Forms from Dialogs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37522294/calling-forms-from-dialogs/37525465#37525465)

Here is the code extract from that answer:

```
var myform = new FormDialog<CreateNewLeadForm>(new CreateNewLeadForm(), CreateNewLeadForm.BuildForm, FormOptions.PromptInStart, null);

context.Call<CreateNewLeadForm>(myform, FormCompleteCallback);
```

Another SO question discusses the subject in more general:

[Handling multiple dialogs in Microsoft bot framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37169371/handling-multiple-dialogs-in-microsoft-bot-framework)

Comment: thanks. but first code sample shows how to call Form from Dialog. I need to call Dialog from Form. Attribute based solution is just my suggestion