# MS BOT change root dialog

Tags: c#, botframework

Is exist way to change root dialog to different one during conversation:

> Conversation.SendAsync((IMessageActivity)context.Activity, () => new
>   RootDialogA())

We have application where it start with one rootdialog and on some point we want to run another root dialog:

> Conversation.SendAsync((IMessageActivity)context.Activity, () => new
>   RootDialogB())

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling multiple dialogs in Microsoft bot framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37169371/handling-multiple-dialogs-in-microsoft-bot-framework)

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is.  Using `context.Call()` or `context.Forward()` you can switch between dialogs.  Please take a look at [this sample project](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-BasicMultiDialog)

Generally what people do is have a root dialog that routes to another dialog based on the context of the conversation. Here is an example from the sample I think where the root dialog is routing to another dialog using the `context.Call()` method:

```
private async Task SendWelcomeMessageAsync(IDialogContext context)
{
    await context.PostAsync("Hi, I'm the Basic Multi Dialog bot. Let's get started.");

    context.Call(new NameDialog(), this.NameDialogResumeAfter);
}
```

You must provide a resume after method that fires off when the called dialog has completed.  In the sample it looks like this:

```
private async Task NameDialogResumeAfter(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> result)
{
    try
    {
        this.name = await result;

        context.Call(new AgeDialog(this.name), this.AgeDialogResumeAfter);
    }
    catch (TooManyAttemptsException)
    {
        await context.PostAsync("I'm sorry, I'm having issues understanding you. Let's try again.");

        await this.SendWelcomeMessageAsync(context);
    }
}
```