# How to trigger CallBack method on carousel Hero Card action in Bot Framework C#

Tags: c#, botframework

I am working on BOT Framework(C#), I am facing one issue and need your help.
Below code is for showing the carousel of Hero card and on the selection of one of Hero Card I want to call a callback method, in below example you can see **OnCardSelection** is the method which I want to call on Card selection, but on execution of line **context.Wait(onCardSelection)** i am getting below error

> invalid need: expected Call, have Wait

and may be due to this it is ending the conversation and consider further action (Click on Hero card) as a new conversation.
Also, I want to access details of the card in **OnCardSelection** method.
How to achieve this.
Thank you.

```
[LuisModel("your sub key", "secret")]
[Serializable]
public class BotManager : LuisDialog<object>
{
    public async Task RaiseTicket(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
     PromptDialog.Confirm(
                    context: context,
                    resume: ResumeAndHandleConfirmRaiseTicketAsync,
                    prompt: "It looks like you want to raise a ticket. Do you want to continue?",
                    retry: "I didn't understand. Please try again.");
    }


    private async Task ResumeAndHandleConfirmRaiseTicketAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<bool> argument)
    {
        bool choicesAreCorrect = await argument;
        if (choicesAreCorrect)
        {
           RaiseTicket objRaiseTicket = new RaiseTicket();
           await objRaiseTicket.StartAsync(context);
        }
        else
        {
           await context.PostAsync("Okay");
        }
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class RaiseTicket
{
       public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
       {
          TypeOfTicket typeOfTicket;
          context.UserData.TryGetValue("TypeOfTicket", out typeOfTicket);
          if (typeOfTicket == TypeOfTicket.None)
          {
              //RaiseTicket
          }
          else
          {
              await PickExactCategory(context);
          }
       }

        public async Task PickExactCategory(IDialogContext context)
        {
            var message = context.MakeMessage();
            message.AttachmentLayout = AttachmentLayoutTypes.Carousel;
            message.Attachments = GetCardsAttachments(categoryList);
            await context.PostAsync(message);
            context.Wait(OnCardSelection);
        }


        protected async Task OnCardSelection(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
        {
             var answer = await result;
             context.Done(new object());
        }

        private IList<Attachment> GetCardsAttachments(Categorylist[] categoryList)
        {
            List<Attachment> lstAttachment = new List<Attachment>();
            foreach (Categorylist item in categoryList)
            {
               lstAttachment.Add(GetHeroCard(
               item.Title, item.SubTitle,item.Text,
               new CardAction(ActionTypes.ImBack, "Select", value: item.Tier3)));
            }
           return lstAttachment;
        }

        private static Attachment GetHeroCard(string title, string subtitle, string text, CardAction cardAction)
        {
            var heroCard = new HeroCard
            {
              Title = title,
              Subtitle = subtitle,
              Text = text,
              Buttons = new List<CardAction>() { cardAction },
            };
        return heroCard.ToAttachment();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is your code embedded in a dialog? I tried to complete your code inside a dialog, it works fine by my side. If it is needed, I can give you my code sample as an answer below.

Comment: Hi Grace, Thank you for taking out your time to read the problem.The code is embedded in the dialog. I have edited the post and added the rest of the code. It will be great if you share your code.

Comment: have you checked my answer, any update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because how you are trying to call your child dialog `RaiseTicket`.

First of all, if it is a dialog it should implement the `IDialog` interface.

Then you will have to call or forward a message to the dialog. You shouldn't manually call the `StartAsync` method.

You can read [Handling multiple dialogs in Microsoft bot framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37169371/handling-multiple-dialogs-in-microsoft-bot-framework/37169696#37169696) or [Calling Forms from Dialogs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37522294/calling-forms-from-dialogs/37525465#37525465) to understand more how the `Call` / `Forward` methods work. Also, you can review the [Manage conversation flow with dialogs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-manage-conversation-flow) article from the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

As Ezequiel Jadib said, problem is how you call the `RaiseTicket`, and `RaiseTicket` should implement the `IDialog` interface.

You can modify the `RaiseTicket` for example like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class RaiseTicket: IDialog<object>
{

    public Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        context.Wait(PickExactCategory);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public async Task PickExactCategory(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        var message = context.MakeMessage();
        message.AttachmentLayout = AttachmentLayoutTypes.Carousel;
        message.Attachments = GetCardsAttachments(categoryList);
        await context.PostAsync(message);
        context.Wait(OnCardSelection);
    }

    public async Task OnCardSelection(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        var answer = await result as IMessageActivity;
        context.Done(new object());
    }

    private IList<Attachment> GetCardsAttachments(List<Categorylist> categoryList)
    {
        List<Attachment> lstAttachment = new List<Attachment>();
        foreach (Categorylist item in categoryList)
        {
            lstAttachment.Add(GetHeroCard(
            item.Title, item.SubTitle, item.Text,
            new CardAction(ActionTypes.ImBack, "Select", value: item.Tier3)));
        }
        return lstAttachment;
    }

    private static Attachment GetHeroCard(string title, string subtitle, string text, CardAction cardAction)
    {
        var heroCard = new HeroCard
        {
            Title = title,
            Subtitle = subtitle,
            Text = text,
            Buttons = new List<CardAction>() { cardAction },
        };
        return heroCard.ToAttachment();
    }
}
```

Then call this `RaiseTicket` dialog in your `BotManager` for example like this:

```
var dialog = new RaiseTicket();
await context.Forward(dialog, dialog.OnCardSelection, null, CancellationToken.None);
```