# How to open multiple conversation with the same bot and user?

Tags: botframework

I am currently trying to create a bot using Microsoft bot service in order to open multiple dialog box on messenger with the same user. I try to open different conversation for different topics. for example, if there's 3 topics: topic1, topic2, topic3. I want to open 3 dialog boxes in parallel name: topic 1 topic 2 topic 3. There is no code because the only one I found is about dialog waterfall and I want parallel conversation not a waterfall. I also look for the bot.beginDialog() function, but in the documentation it is said "Any current conversation between the bot and user will be replaced with a new dialog stack." But I want to have a different conversation running at the same time. Iam usinf node.js. Is it possible? If it is how ?

```
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, [
function (session) {
    session.send("Welcome to the dinner reservation.");
    session.beginDialog('topic1');
},
function (session, results) {
    session.dialogData.topic1 = results.response;
    session.beginDialog('topic2');
},
function (session, results) {
    session.dialogData.topic2 = results.response;
    session.beginDialog('topic3');
},
function (session, results) {
    session.dialogData.topic3 = results.response;
    session.endDialog();
}
```

])

Here we have the three dialogs executing one after another in the same conversation :

What i have :

CONVERSATION 1
topic1
topic2
topic3
Conversation end

What i want:

CONVERSATION 1
topic1
Conversation end

CONVERSATION 2
topic2
Conversation end

CONVERSATION 3
topic3
Conversation end

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What have you tried so far with a code example? ([I downvoted because there is no code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/))* / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling multiple dialogs in Microsoft bot framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37169371/handling-multiple-dialogs-in-microsoft-bot-framework)

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible on FB Messenger (you are asking about FB Messenger, correct?), but I also don't create the need to create a new conversation with the user two additional times... Can you explain your use case?

Comment: Yes this is about Facebook messenger and with more research, I found out this is impossible to do it. The point was for user's to have a better view of the different topics and have a better readability of the conversation flow. Use case example : if someone want's to participate to an auction sale about different product he could have one conversation per product.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible using Facebook Messenger.